# Teradata platform has an ETL tool?

Tags: bigdata, teradata, etl, business-intelligence

Probably  i'm gonna work with teradata and was wondering it's platform have it's own ETL tool.

If not, what would be better integrated with teradata, power center?

Comment: Teradata has multiple tools for ETL. You'll need to install `Teradata Tools & Utilities" for whatever OS you are using (TTU). In there is BTEQ which is their command line interface as well as FastLoad, MLoad, and TPT. TPT is the most robust as it wraps up the other tools into a common scripting language.

Comment: If you're looking for a fancy ETL tool with a gui and such, like datastage or Talend, then the answer is no.  I haven't done any tool-based ETL on Teradata in a few years, but datastage at least could use teradata specific things like fload, mload.

Comment: Informatica starting with the latest versions (9.x+) is now free to download and install; it already has plug-ins to use tpt/mload/fastload, as well as record-based source/transformation/target processing, which comes closest to bteq.